# Getting no rows from sqlite3 in iOS app

Tags: ios, ios4, sqlite, database-connection

The following code returns no rows, but when I run the query in sqlite3 in Terminal, I get the result I expect. So I guess there is some trivial mistake here:

```
- (void)initializeDatabaseWithFilter:(NSString *)filter
{
    NSMutableArray *fristArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.frister = fristArray;
    [fristArray release];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Frister.sqlite"];
    if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK){
        // Get primary key for all entries with filter
        const char *sql = "SELECT fristKey FROM frister WHERE ? = 1";
        sqlite3_stmt *statement;
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
            NSAssert1(0,@"Error: Failed to prepare statement with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [filter UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        NSLog(@"%@",filter); // lets me see if the filter column name is passed to the method.
        int i = 0; // this is to see if I get some rows in return
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            i++;
            int primaryKey = sqlite3_column_int(statement,0);
            Frist *td = [[Frist alloc] inithWithOwnerID:primaryKey database:database];

            [frister addObject:td];
            [td release];
        }
        NSLog(@"%d",i); // If I get some results, I should get a number here...
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    } else {
        sqlite3_close(database);
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to open database with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }
}
```

I would really like some help here :)

Comment: Only masochists use the SQLite C API in Objective-C.  [Use FMDB](http://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) or [CoreData](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) instead.

Comment: Yeah, next app will be something else than sqlite, but now Im stuck with it for this project... :(

Comment: @Spiff_no FMDB is a wrapper around SQLite.  It allows you to manipulate SQLite databases without having to do all that `sqlite3_prepare_v2` junk.  IOW, it lets you focus on actually writing the functionality of the app instead of wondering why your prepared statement isn't stepping properly.

Comment: Thanks, Dave, Ill try to figure out FMDB, but so far I have seen, aint there much documentation for it.

Comment: @Spiff_no yeah, there's not a lot of concrete documentation, but the example that comes in the source shows you pretty much everything you need to know. If you have specific questions, just ask and we'll be happy to help :)

Comment: Others have asked the same question here before, but no-one ever got an answer to it. This is the last couple of lines of code for my project, so using a wrapper or Core Data would mean I have to rewrite lots of code. I would really love an answer to this problem :)

Comment: @Dave DeLong: Im a n00b to Objective-C and when I downloaded and opened up the FMDB I almost broke into tears. I don't understand anything. How should I add this to my project? Where do I specify the database? This confuses me even more. The sqlite3 api is at least understandable to some point ;)   But if you have time to babysit me through this process, Im willing to try ;)

Comment: @spiff_no i added an answer, since it's too much info for a single comment. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you've already accepted an answer, but I think I see the problem in your sqlite call.

In the terminal, I guess you're doing a query something like this:

```
SELECT fristKey FROM frister WHERE column = 1
```

But your code is *not* doing an equivalent query. It is instead doing a query like this:

```
SELECT fristKey FROM frister WHERE 'column' = 1
```

Since the string "column" is never going to be equal to 1, your query is not going to give any results. You cannot bind a column name into a parameterized query, only a literal value.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is a direct explanation to my problem in the first place, so Ill mark it as an accepted answer as well. :)

Answer (score 2):

(Adding this as an answer since it would be pretty cumbersome to put it as a comment)

I strongly suggest using [FMDB](http://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) to interact with the database instead.  It's a wrapper around the SQLite C API that makes it very easy to interact with a database.  Your code could be changed to use it with pretty minimal intervention.  Here's what it would look like:

```
- (void)initializeDatabaseWithFilter:(NSString *)filter
{
    self.frister = [NSMutableArray array];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Frister.sqlite"];

    FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:path];
    if ([db open]) {
        NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT fristKey FROM frister WHERE %@ = 1", filter];
        FMResultSet *results = [db executeQuery:sql];
        while([results next]) {
            int primaryKey = [results intForColumn:@"fristKey"];
            Frist *td = [[Frist alloc] initWithOwnerID:primaryKey database:db];
            [[self frister] addObject:td];
            [td release];
        }
        [db close];
    }
}
```

Doesn't that look a **TON** more readable?  It's pretty easy to see that you're executing a query, iterating through the results, and pulling the "fristKey" out in order to make a "Frist" object.  You don't have to worry about `sqlite3_open`, preparing statements, binding parameters, or finalizing statements.

The other thing you'd have to change is the `Frist` object: it needs to accept a `FMDatabase*` as it's "database" instead of a `sqlite3*`.  You may also consider just opening the database once and then leaving it open until you don't need it anymore (otherwise you'll have to `-open` it every time you want to execute something; this is entirely up to you).

To include FMDB in your app, download the code from Github, and then copy the FMDatabase, FMDatabaseAdditions, and FMResultSet files (all 6) into your app, and `#import` them where you'll need to interact with the database.  You'll still need to link against sqlite3.dylib.

Just be sure you honor the (very permissive) [license](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb/blob/master/LICENSE.txt).

Comment: First of all, YES, it looks a lot more readable.. Ill try it right now! :)

Comment: It looks nice so far, but now I get an error in line 14 of the code you provided: No '-initWithOwnerID:database:' method found. I did not have this error before in my code.

Comment: @spiff_no ah.  it's misspelled as `inithWithOwnerID` in your original code.

Comment: oh, I should have seen it myself ;) Well, anyway, Im going for the wrapper in this project, probably Ill try out Core Data next time :)